# Can I use mathematica's StringReplace to write the row number of a text file?

Tags: string, for-loop, text, replace, wolfram-mathematica

I have a mathematica program which output is a text file that for reasons will be used in python as input.

```
savedXText = ExportString[savedX, "Text"];    
savedXText2 = 
  StringReplace[
   savedXText, {"[" -> "(", "]" -> ")", 
    "t" -> "m.lammda[i]*180/np.pi", "u" -> "m.phi[i]*180/np.pi"}];

Export["testOutputX.txt", savedXText2];
```

`testOutputX.txt` has a number of rows which can vary. I need to write instead of just `m.lammda` and `m.phi` the number of row. If the file has three rows, I would need `m.lammda1` and `m.phi1`, `m.lammda2` and `m.phi2`and `m.lammda3` and `m.phi3` in each row of `testOutputX.txt`

My idea is to use a for loop, charge each row of `savedX` and then do the string replace in which the value of the variable used to count the loop is written as text in the `StringReplace`.

I have constructed a for loop that picks each row of `savedX` and does the StringReplace

```
savedXReplaced = Table[RandomInteger[i, lengthLoop], {i, 1, lengthLoop}];
    For[i = 1, i < lengthLoop + 1, i++, 
 savedXTextTemp = ExportString[savedX[[i]], "Text"]; 
 savedXTextTemp2 = 
  StringReplace[
   savedXTextTemp, {"[" -> "(", "]" -> ")", 
    "t" -> "m.lammda[i]*180/np.pi", "u" -> "m.phi[i]*180/np.pi"}]; 
 Print[savedXTextTemp2]; savedXReplaced[[i]] = savedXTextTemp2]
```

I however have looked at the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html) of `StringReplace` and I haven't been able to find how to write the value of `i`, the variable used in this for loop.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
For[i = 1, i < lengthLoop + 1, i++,
 savedXTextTemp = ExportString[savedX[[i]], "Text"];
 savedXTextTemp2 = StringReplace[
   savedXTextTemp, {"[" -> "(", "]" -> ")",
    "t" -> StringJoin["m.lammda", ToString[i], "*180/np.pi"],
    "u" -> StringJoin["m.phi", ToString[i], "*180/np.pi"]}];
 Print[savedXTextTemp2]; savedXReplaced[[i]] = savedXTextTemp2]
```